# Forward Proxy and ECS sticky session

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, proxy, amazon-ecs, api-gateway

We are trying to build an application which involves clients communicating to a server (setup via ECS). Client calls are forwarded to the server via a forward proxy. I understand that we can enable sticky sessions via load balancer. Will a sticky session still hold good if we are using a forward proxy? If not then is there a way to create a sticky session between the client and server?

Comment: Are these HTTP sessions? If the forward proxy maintains the original session cookies, then it should work fine. Cookies are how AWS Application Load Balancers manage sticky sessions.